# LSTM with rnn cuda()?

Tags: cuda, lstm

I have the following model:

```
model = nn.Sequential()
model:add(nn.Sequencer(nn.LookupTable(nIndex, hiddenSize)))
model:add(nn.Sequencer(nn.FastLSTM(hiddenSize, hiddenSize, rho)))
model:add(nn.Sequencer(nn.Linear(hiddenSize, nIndex)))
model:add(nn.Sequencer(nn.LogSoftMax()))
```

then I put the model on cuda  by:

```
model:cuda()
```

and I try to forward an input (cudatensor) and it breaks .

Is FastLSTM incompatible with cuda ?

the message:

```
[string "local f = function() return targets:cuda() en..."]:1: attempt to  call method 'cuda' (a nil value)
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to introduce a few computations on cuda with the following changes: 
- first put the model ans the criterion on cuda by :

```
model=model:cuda()
criterion=criterion:cuda()
```

-second I built a table of cuda tensor that I provided as targets by :

```
local targetscudatable={}
for i = 1, #targets do
  table.insert(targetscudatable, targets[i]:cuda())
end
```

then it works, but I wonder if I can have more data sent to cuda, like the inputs. Anyway I already had a speed increase od 500% wich is not to bad

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to require the **cunn** package :

`require 'cunn'`